# How to update Firefox Add-ons when using Firefox in a sandbox?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, redhat-enterprise-linux, scientific-linux

The SELinux sandbox works like this: If I start Firefox in a sandbox then the original Firefox directory gets copied to a temporary place, and any changes done in the sandboxed Firefox get's deleted if I close the browser.

But I always want to use the sandboxed Firefox. This means that if there are any updates to a Firefox Add-on, they will be updated in the sandbox, but the updates will be deleted when I close the browser, and when I next open the sandboxed firefox the old add-ons will be used...

I think that updating firefox Add-ons could be done via the repositories of the OS, but.. I didn't found them using "yum search all adblock", for example.

Are there any ways to solve this problem? I always need to use fresh Firefox Add-ons!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to launch Firefox **out** of the sandbox, update your addons through the `about:addons` page, and close it again.
You can't update them through yum cause they're not part of your OS distribution, but are just Firefox addons.